# Globally accessible style in class library

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, material-design-in-xaml

I have a class library where I'm defining (basically extending) some controls such as `TextBox`, `Button` etc. I'm also using [`MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit`](https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit) which is used to stylize controls. So my class library will essentially have controls with my own extended functionality and they will look like styles defined in `MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit`.

Now my question is, since I don't have `App.xaml` in class library project, where should I write the XAML code to import the styles of `MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit`, so that they will be applied to my extended controls? What is the place in class library where you can specify styles which are globally accessible and are applied to all the controls?

I searched about this but didn't find what I want. Please help.

---

**Update:** Here is my code (not working).

MaterialTextBox.cs

```
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace MaterialControls
{
    public class MaterialTextBox : TextBox
    {
        ... some extra features here (no XAML file for this class, just this .cs)...
    }
}
```

Themes.xaml (this will contain all the global styles)

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MaterialControls">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Light.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />

        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style TargetType="local:MaterialTextBox">
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="100"/>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>

    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Now I want these styles to apply to `MaterialTextBox` so that wherever I use it, it should come with this look and featues out of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

I was using `Class Library` project where I actually should have used `WPF Custom Control Library` project. Here project type is important otherwise you will have to play with `.csproj` file to make it work.

So now created a new `WPF Custom Control Library` project (`New Project > Windows > Classic Desktop > WPF Custom Control Library` template). This project has `Themes\Generic.xaml` file which will be used as a default location for styles.

Comment: How is this answer related to the original question...?

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. At the time of posting the question I wasn't aware of this. So I asked the question based on what I was doing but this is the right solution. If somebody in future does the similar thing like me then this answer would be helpful. But I agree, the question is about Class Library and this is not the exact answer if looked at it that way.

Comment: I answered your question but you didn't even bother to vote the answer up. Instead you provided your own answer that has nothing to do with your queston. That makes sense. Or not.

Comment: Calm down friend. I didn't up-vote it because it didn't solve the problem. Although, now I realize the way question is framed is wrong and is kind of ambiguous. That could be because of my lack of knowledge on the topic. Anyways I will be deleting the question as I think it will be more confusing than helpful.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the place in class library where you can specify styles which are globally accessible and are applied to all the controls?

There is none really. In a single resource dictionary, you could use `<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>` to import resources that the resources that you define in the resource Dictionary itself are based on, e.g.:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication8">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Light.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    <Style TargetType="...">
        <!-- style based on MaterialDesignTheme -->
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

But there is no concept of an `App.xaml` or some kind of "global resource cache" in a class library.

Comment: Not working. Tried adding a xaml file to project, put the above code with some simple styles to test. And it has no effect. Please read updated question.

Comment: Read my answer again. You should put the MaterialTextBox style *afrer* </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>.

Comment: Ahh ok.. Didn't catch that. Anyways, did the changes and it's not working. Is it working at your end? What is the `Build Action` and `Custom Tool` for the xaml file?

Comment: The build action of a ResourceDictionary should always be Page.

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept for a dictionary in the assembly which is automaticaly merged into app.xaml. But for a default control style there is one.

To assign a default style set the `DefaultStyleKeyProperty` for the control.

```
    static MaterialTextBox() {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MaterialTextBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MaterialTextBox)));
    }
```

and in Themes\Generic.xaml add the style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MaterialTextBox}">
...
</Style>
```

- Do not merge Themes\Generic.xaml in your App.xaml
- do only add default styles for controls created in this assembly.

The resources in Themes\Generic.xaml  are not globaly available, but through the DefaultStyleKeyProperty the resource is found and assigned to the control.